# Use factory object to initialize scope object value in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have created a factory in my project as follows,

```
app.factory('userFactory', userFactory);

function userFactory() {
var userInitialValueSettings = {
    UserId: '',
    FullName: '',
    Location: '',
    Phone: '',
    Ext: '',
    Fax: '',
    Email: '',
    IsExternalUser: false,
    Password: '',
    UserMustChangePassword: false,
    PasswordNeverExpires: false
}

return {
    userInitailValues: userInitialValueSettings
}
}
```

I used the userInitialValues object of the factory to initialize one of my scope object as given below.

```
$scope.user = userFactory.userInitailValues;
```

I used the properties of $scope.user as the models of some input textboxes. I have a clear button in my form. I need to clear the textboxes while clicking the clear button. So I hooked the following function in the clear button click.

```
$scope.cancelAddUserDialoge = function () {
    $scope.user = userFactory.userInitailValues;
}
```

But the text fields are not getting cleared. What is the issue? Can anybody help me? If I use the following method in the clear button click and clear each model property individually then, the textboxes are getting cleared.

```
function ResetUserModel() {
    $scope.user.UserId= '',
    $scope.user.FullName = '',
    $scope.user.Location = '',
    $scope.user.Phone = '',
    $scope.user.Ext = '',
    $scope.user.Fax = ''
    $scope.user.Email = '',
    $scope.user.IsExternalUser = false,
    $scope.user.Password = '',
    $scope.user.UserMustChangePassword =false,
    $scope.user.PasswordNeverExpires =false
}
```

Why I cannot use the factory object to clear the models? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assiging object without copying it

```
$scope.user = userFactory.userInitailValues;
```

Object will keep reference during assigning .

If one side is changed another will automatically be changed.

So when you assigned without using copy,you change in form will also make change in `userInitailValues`.  ultimately you are re-assigning `$scope.user` in the `$scope.user`.

Try like this

```
$scope.user = angular.copy(userFactory.userInitailValues);
```

Comment: Probably better to make `userFactory.userInitialValues` a function that returns a copy then the caller(s) don't have to always remember to copy before use.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already tried it. But it didn't worked. I found that, it is 2 way updating. So I used angular.copy as you suggested. It is working in initialization while loading. But one clear button click the text fields are not getting clear.

Comment: @NOBLEM.O. can you make a fiddle and provide link to me ?

Answer (score 1):

You initialize the values only once. Then `$scope.user` links to the values and you change these values directly. I would suggest you to create initial data next way:

```
app.factory('userFactory', userFactory);

function userFactory() {

    return { 
      init : function() {
        return { 
          UserId: '',
          FullName: '',
          Location: '',
          Phone: '',
          Ext: '',
          Fax: '',
          Email: '',
          IsExternalUser: false,
          Password: '',
          UserMustChangePassword: false,
          PasswordNeverExpires: false 
        };
      }
   };
}
```

Then in you controller init data

```
$scope.user = userFactory.init();
```

and reset

```
$scope.cancelAddUserDialoge = function () {
    $scope.user = userFactory.init();
}
```

Here the fixed fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/takf64v6/